# Are there any limits on the no of parameters passed or the lenght of the parameters while using pagereference

Tags: apex, visualforce

Are there any limitations on the no of characters passed as parameters using

```
pr.getParameters().put('sUsers', convertListtoString(selectedUsers));
```

Just wanted to sure i would not hit any limits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no Salesforce limits for this, but you should be aware of browser URL length limits. If you can keep the URL under 2000 characters, they'll work in virtually any combination of client and server software. For a more detailed explanation, visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers).

Answer (score 0):

If it is more than 10 items in a `set<String>` that is passed as an URL parameter, it breaks silently!