# Prepopulating a record with a url > 2048 characters

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a page layout, where the user clicks a button that creates a partial copy of the current opportunity. We are prepopulating the new record with a lot of values from the existing record. I'm doing this by URL hacking.

The problem is that as I'm building out the URL, **I'm beyond 2048 characters, is that going to be an issue?** How do I resolve this?

I can't overwrite the standard edit page with visualforce, because it would become a maintainance nightmare.

Comment: n.b. - not directly related to your question but fieldsets can make creation/maintenance of VF pages much more maintainable when there are large numbers of fields - see http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/fieldset-visualforce-page-salesforce/ for example

Comment: Time to break out the toolkits and use the button to create the record then redirect the user to the edit page for the newly created record as Keith C suggested below. the main issue would be if the user clicks cancel how to delete the record if you no longer want it....

Comment: @Eric- i thought about that but ruled it out. you can't overwrite the cancel button on a standard edit screen, that turns into a bigger problem, i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [common advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers#answer-417184) is to not risk URLs longer than 2k because there are just too many browser versions out there to be sure your code will work everywhere if the URL is larger. You typically can't control what browser your users are going to use.

You can add a button to layout-based UI that copies the existing object fields you want copying and then presents it in an edit page. I know that is not great as it doesn't follow the same pattern as Clone (where the record is only persisted when Save is clicked). But you could call the button something like "Copy and Edit" to try to communicate what it is actually doing...

Answer (score 1):

Do you know for sure that the 2048 limit is going to be an issue? This [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11651/are-there-any-limits-on-the-no-of-parameters-passed-or-the-lenght-of-the-paramet) suggests not. The length of a URL is generally browser specific, do a bit of googling and you'll see the lengths for each. Salesforce may well truncate GET requests as well.

However, as a quick test I was just built a URL > 3000 and then was able to echo the value back in a Visualforce page:

e.g., URL and page:

```
https://eu0.salesforce.com/apex/TestURL?test=01234567890[truncated the rest]


<apex:page >
    <apex:outputText value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.test}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Whether you can do so successfully with a URL Hack I don't know.

Comment: I don't know if 2048 will be an issue. We are using IE 9, and URL hacking is not really supported by SF.  I'm not sure how to reliably test the long urls. any advice?

Comment: Test it and see, the only way to find out for sure unless someone else has some direct experience that they can offer.

Comment: If you intend to support Internet Explorer 9, you will be limited to 2048 characters, per [this article](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html). Salesforce.com has no problem with ridiculously long URLs.

Comment: @sfdcfox so you're saying my options are move to a new browser or if I stay on IE, keep it under 2048?

Comment: @nivyaj You are limited to 2048 characters for IE 9, and salesforce.com itself (at least VF pages), croaks at about 7600 characters (slightly longer).